# Can some post data get lost due to poor internet in php?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

During a form submission (using post method) is it possible that the php url for form action is called but the whole post data is lost due to internet problem? Also is it possible that some of the fields are lost? I'm currently working on a form which has more than 20 fields, during test in 2 cases once the whole post data was lost and on another case just a single field's data was lost. My understanding is, whole post data might be lost due to a 302 redirect but how does the data of a single field get lost?

That field mentioned is Address, which is stored in the database as varchar also I'm using code igniter which allows me to read the posted data using `$this->input->post('address')` if that helps.

Comment: No, you can be pretty sure a request is either complete or aborted entirely.

Comment: the single field lost was 'address'? What does "lost" mean?

Comment: By lost I mean the data of that field was not posted, all other field's data was posted however on that case.

Comment: Thanks deceze that was helpful